# Print runtime usercontrol silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, exception, printing, runtime

My silverlight application has a usercontrol  (called `CertificatePrintControl`) that is used to display and print some information.
I would like, inside another control, to istantiate the printCtl and print the content at runtime.
The example is:

```
foreach (var certId in CertToPrint)
    {
        var certPrintController = new CertificatePrintControl() { PrintDocument = pd, CertGuid = certId };
        certPrintController.Print();
        certPrintController = null;
    }
```

The problem is that inside the CertificatePrintControl there's this code

```
    void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var oldW = lstMainPrintCertificate.Width;
            var oldH = lstMainPrintCertificate.Height;
            lstMainPrintCertificate.Width = e.PrintableArea.Width;
            lstMainPrintCertificate.Height = e.PrintableArea.Height;
            e.PageVisual = lstMainPrintCertificate;
            lstMainPrintCertificate.Width = oldW;
            lstMainPrintCertificate.Height = oldH;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            //
        }
    }
```

that gives

```
 {System.InvalidOperationException: Element is already the child of another element.
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase obj, DependencyProperty property, DependencyObject doh)
   at System.Windows.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs.set_PageVisual(UIElement value)
   at com.breathesaftey.Control.CertificatePrintControl.pd_PrintPage(Object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)}
```

I may have understood why but I can't find a workaround.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [Silverlight reporting](http://silverlightreporting.codeplex.com/)

and I resolved the issue...